# Vue - get current wordpress user data using axios

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, rest, axios

Im trying to pull the current logged in user data into my headless frontend but data always returns empty - i think its to do with setting a nonce?

```
axios
    .get('https://example.com/wp-json/v1/get-user')
    .then(response => ( console.log(response) ));
```

and in functions file

```
$user_id = "";

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_custom_users_api');

function add_custom_users_api(){
    $GLOBALS['user_id'] = get_current_user_id();

    register_rest_route( 'v1', 'get-user', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_custom_users_data',
        'nonce'     => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ),
    ));
}
//Customize the callback to your liking
function get_custom_users_data(){
    return get_user_by( 'id', $GLOBALS['user_id'] );
}
```

What am i missing? The idea is the user will login on the main website and then on this headless area will be authorised.

Comment: You need to do some test, like, directly return inside your function a dumb data. Check the status code of the response. We can't really help without more information about the api response and when something go wrong.